# Chest pain accompanied with nausea

Tags: heart-attack, stroke, anti-anxiety-meds

My mom says she woke up with chest pains and nausea twice last night is this a early warning sign of heart attack or stroke? She takes Xanax on the regular not sure if that could have anything to do with it....

Comment: Not necessary heart attack, but "heart-related chest pain" or "angina pectoris" due to "ischemic heart disease" is one of the possible causes. Such pain is triggered by exercise and stress and tends to radiate down the left arm. If this what she experienced is different or worse from what she usually feels, she should maybe go to a cardiologist and do some tests. A primary doctor can be a good start. It sounds nothing like stroke. It could be just heartburn due to acid reflux. People here do not like to take responsibility for something what might be potentially a serious condition.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). For any health concern you should consult with your (or your mom's) doctor, in person. A diagnosis can't be made over the internet. That's why personal medical advice is strictly off-topic here. For more info on the site policies, please take our [tour] or visit the [help].

Comment: I was just wondering if there was any need for concern (for lack of better words)

Comment: Just for future reference -- just change the person pronouns to "If a person were to experience" -- try to make it less about personal medical advice to avoid being closed.